# Is a pulse of white noise still properly described as stationary?

Tags: stationary

I understand that a signal that is white noise is stationary (or more properly that the process generating it is stationary).

What if the white noise is delivered as a single pulse or a series of pulses with silence between them? Is that still stationary, or does the pulsatility suddenly convert this into a non-stationary system?

If it is no longer stationary, is there a term of art conveying the information that the signal within the pulse is stationary (e.g., a pure tone or white noise) rather than  a non-stationary natural or musical sound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pulsed process is not stationary. You can use the term "quasi-stationary" to describe a process that looks stationary in short time scales (e.g. during silence, or in the middle of a pulse).

Comment: What I really want is a term that excludes audio signals generated by a stationary process, whether the signal is  subsequently pulsed or continuous, but includes all other kinds of audio signals.  I can't quite get away with "signals that are not stationary and not quasi-stationary" -- can you think of a phrase that would meet the need?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: basically you can classify most signals as "stationary", "non-stationary" and "quasi-stationary", where "quasi-stationary" is a fuzzy term that means "the signal is mathematically non-stationary but we'll say it is stationary  over the time frames we're interested in". Does that help?

Comment: Yes, that helps. Thank you